# Other computers can't connect to my server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've Just created a minecraft 1.11.2 server(the official download from minecraft.net), and set it up. I can join it from my computer using localhost. However, no other computers can connect to it(they get the message:"can't connect to server". I can't connect to it using the ip either. I am running OX Yosemite and have no firewall on. Also, I've made sure to whitelist the other computer(which is not on the same LAN network). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have not port-forwarded your router.

This guide is for a much older version of Minecraft, but the port-forwarding portion is still good. Follow the guide thoroughly.

https://portforward.com/softwareguides/minecraft/portforward-minecraft.htm

If you're in a situation where you're unable to port-forward (living on a University Campus, or otherwise unable to access the router configuration), you can look into a Virtual Private Network program, such as [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/).

Be warned that Hamachi modifies your network adapter to work, meaning you'll need some networking know-how to fix things if something breaks.

Comment: I tried following the tutorial but my router isn't on the list. I'll try to find another tutorial on port forwarding.

Comment: also, as I said, I don't have a firewall so I don't think I need to port forward. Is that true?

Comment: Milo, this is not true. Your router controls traffic where this is concerned and needs to be port forwarded to allow outside traffic to reach your server. Find the same brand of router and the steps should be similar enough.